# Why BigQuery JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR Return Null for Some?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have loaded JSON formatted string into BigQuery and trying to get the key and value pair using JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR, the other keys work but I don't understand why the same does not work with integer?

See User.Type and User.Test:

```
SELECT *
, JSON_QUERY(json, "$.User") User
, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY(json, "$.User"), '"', ''), "$.Key") User_Key
, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY(json, "$.User"), '"', ''), r': False', ': false'), r': True', ': true'), "$.IsNew") User_IsNew
, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY(json, "$.User"), '"', ''), "$.Type") User_Type
, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY(json, "$.User"), '"', ''), "$.Test") User_Test

FROM(
SELECT "{'User': \"{'Key': 'abc123', 'IsNew': False, 'Type': 2, 'Test': '123'}\"}" json
)
```

[image: BigQuery Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `json` doesn't seem a valid json string. Especially `False` is not defined in JSON as you already try to convert it with `false` in your query.

Remaining string right after **False** is not valid any more, so **User_Type** and **User_Test** column seems to return **null**.

If you fix this before you apply **JSON** functions to your data, you will get the result you want.

```sql
SELECT *
, JSON_QUERY(json, "$.User") User
, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY(json, "$.User"), '"', ''), "$.Key") User_Key
, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY(json, "$.User"), '"', ''), "$.IsNew") User_IsNew
, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY(json, "$.User"), '"', ''), "$.Type") User_Type
, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY(json, "$.User"), '"', ''), "$.Test") User_Test
FROM (
  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(json, ': True', ': true'), ': False', ': false') json 
    FROM (
      SELECT "{'User': \"{'Key': 'abc123', 'IsNew': False, 'Type': 2, 'Test': '123'}\"}" json
    )
);
```

[image]

and also consider below more concise query.

```sql
SELECT *,
       JSON_VALUE(User, '$.Key') User_Key,
       JSON_VALUE(User, '$.IsNew') User_IsNew,
       JSON_VALUE(User, '$.Type') User_Type,
       JSON_VALUE(User, '$.Test') User_Test,
  FROM (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(json, ': True', ': true'), ': False', ': false') json 
      FROM (
        SELECT "{'User': \"{'Key': 'abc123', 'IsNew': False, 'Type': 2, 'Test': '123'}\"}" json
      )
  ), UNNEST([TRIM(JSON_VALUE(json, "$.User"), '"')]) User
```

[image]

Comment: Note : From what I have observed, **JSON Function** acts like SAX parser (stream parser), while **JSON Type** acts like DOM parser (tree parser).

Comment: it works after fixing the boolean in string, thank you!